# Angular "this is undefined" when trying to increment number variable, not sure what I'm doing wrong

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I'm basically counting the number of times an object in an array has 2 keys that equals a certain value. I want to increment that number for each time the condition is met.

if I console.log to see the number of times the 'for' loop is firing, everything is good and all works well. But when I try to do something with this.multidropAccepted I'm suddenly getting undefined errors, even when I'm just trying to read it on the console.

Code:

```
function countAccepted(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].DeliveryStatus == "Accepted" && arr[i].BookingId == "0") {
      console.log("poop");
      this.multidropAccepted++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: where do you call this function? maybe the context you execute the function in does not have multidropAccepted variable?

Comment: in Angular, you define a function like counAccepted(arr){...} -no "function before"- And you must declare your variable before -generally before the constructor

Comment: @Eliseo Now I see, but if that's the case then I need to write the whole function where I call it inside the .subscribe, right? I just gave that a shot and I'm not getting 'cannot find name "countaccepted"'

Comment: if you want to execute a function that you are defined, then use this.myFunction(). "this" is the "component".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Angular with typescript then don't use `function` keyword to write method. As it'll create its own scope & thus you'll not be able to access class level properties using `this` inside it. Update your method code to:

```
countAccepted(arr) {
  for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (arr[i].DeliveryStatus == "Accepted" && arr[i].BookingId == "0") {
      console.log("poop");
      this.multidropAccepted++;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Ah, I see, but then instead of writing the function outside the .subscribe and then calling it inside, I'd just write the whole function inside of it? 

I just gave that a try and I'm getting "cannot find name'count accepted'" from intellisense.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing it like this:

```
let countAccepted = data => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (
            data[i].DeliveryStatus == "Accepted" &&
            data[i].BookingId == "0"
          ) {
            this.multidropAccepted++;
          }
        }
      };
```

Had to have it in the subscription block for it to work and defined before calling it.
I called it at the end to make sure that my table has content in it as the first priority and only then counting these things

```
countAccepted(data)
```

This is how the whole thing looks:

```
constructor(
    private adalService: AdalService,
    private service: DeliveriesService,
    private ngRedux: NgRedux<IAppState>
  ) {
    this.service.getSectionAll();
    this.sectionAllSubscription = this.sectionAll.subscribe(data => {
      let countAccepted = data => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (
            data[i].DeliveryStatus == "Accepted" &&
            data[i].BookingId == "0"
          ) {
            this.multidropAccepted++;
          }
        }
      };

      let countDelivered = data => {
        for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          if (
            data[i].DeliveryStatus == "Delivered" &&
            data[i].BookingId == "0"
          ) {
            this.multidropDelivered++;
          }
        }
      };

      (this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(
        data.filter(
          (value, index, array) =>
            !array.filter(
              (v, i) => JSON.stringify(value) == JSON.stringify(v) && i < index
            ).length
        )
      )),
        (this.dataSource.sort = this.sort),
        (this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator),
        countAccepted(data);
      countDelivered(data);
    });
  }
```